# should vs. have to vs. must in specific context?

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs, auxiliary

In the following situation, which fits best (***should*** or ***must*** or ***have to***):

I think that it is very important to look after the environment. This means that we ***should/must/have to*** cut down the amount of waste that we create.

I was taught that we use ***have to*** to express strong obligation, *when the obligation comes from someone else*.

And that we use ***must*** to express strong obligation, *when the obligation comes from you*.

And to use ***should*** to express mild obligation.

Accordingly, it is **(MUST)** that fits best, but I am still not sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience both "must" and "have to" are used for any strong obligation or need, ether coming from oneself or from an outside source; they can be used interchangeably.

The word "should" (and also the verb "ought to") is used when there is a legal or moral requirement, or when the thing is in some way the **right** or **proper** thing to do, but there is an option not to do it. The reason can still be strong, however. One might say "You should not commit a murder."

The [Merriam-Webster definition of **must**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/must) shows several senses, and that of [have to](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20to) also has several senses but none suggest the distinction between external and internal source of obligation that I can see. The [definition of should](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/should) also has several senses, but one is "to express obligation, propriety, or expediency". Other dictionaries do not seem greatly different on these terms.

I do not agree with the meaniongs states in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, ***must*** and ***have to*** indicate a stronger level of obligation than ***should***.

- “Employees **must** attend the training session on workplace safety.”
  = Attendance at the session is an absolute requirement.  If you don't go, you'll be fired.
- “Employees **have to** attend the training session on workplace safety.”
  = As with *must*, this indicates a requirement, but to my ears *have to*  sounds less forceful and more informal than *must*.
- “Employees **should** attend the training session on workplace safety.”
  = We recommend/prefer that you go, but if something comes up and you can't go, we'll understand.
- “Employees **ought to** attend the training session on workplace safety.”
  = To me, this sounds a bit milder than *should*.  A suggestion.
- “Employees **may** attend the training session on workplace safety.”
  = It's available if you're interested, but we don't really care whether you go or not.

So, the choice of which modal verb to use in a given context depends primarily on the severity of the consequences of **not** doing the thing.

- If it would be **unacceptable**, use **must**.
- If it would be **inconvenient**, use **should**.

“We **must** cut down the amount of waste that we create, before we turn the planet into a *Wall-E*-style giant landfill.”  OK, that might be exaggerating, but you get the idea.

I am unaware of any distinction in usage as to whether the obligation comes from someone else or from yourself.